# How to open large archive (tgz) files?

Tags: tar, archive, 7zip, file-roller

I am switching from Windows to Ubuntu. In Windows, I was using a program for backup which was creating **.7z** files. It is fast and easy to restore a few files from a *huge 7zip archive*.

In Ubuntu, currently I am using *tar* to create **.tgz** archive files. However, when I try to quickly restore a few small files from *a huge .tgz archive*, *Archive Manage (Roller)* or command line *tar* tries to read the whole .tgz file first, which takes too much time.

Which is the recommended archive file format for backup and quick restore?

***Note***: I cannot go with 7zip, because it does not store Linux file access permissions.

Comment: [This Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/244604/285436) suggests `dar` (**d**isk **ar**chive). However, answers in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13633488/4325768) claim that `zip` _can_ store file access permissions. The problem with `tar` (**t**ape **ar**chive) is that it was made for, well, tapes, which are written/read sequentially.

Comment: Thanks.

(1) The default _zip_ command line that comes in Ubuntu repositories seems to work in storing file timestamps and access permissions. It is rather old (*version 3.0 - July 5th 2008*) though!

(2) As for _dar_, I haven't tested too much, but it seems that _Archive Manager_ cannot open *.dar* files!